# Facebook AdInsight API: parsing object

Tags: python, facebook, object

I am using Facebook AdInsight API using a python script. When I query for a particular date using the following snippet:

```
 start_time = '2012-08-01'
 end_time = '2012-08-01'

 account1 = AdAccount('act_XXXXXXXX');
   params = {
             'level' : 'account',
             'time_range': {
                            'since': start_time,
                            'until': end_time},
                            'fields' :'spend',
             };
insights1 = account1.get_insights(params=params)
print(insights1[-1])
```

I get a response:
 {
    "date_start": "2012-08-01",
    "date_stop": "2012-08-01",
    "spend": 573.22
}

This is the only object in the list. I was wondering is there is good way to parse this output into a single comma separated line.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way to do this. I wrote the first result to an intermediate file and then read file searching spend string and using basic split to get the value.

```
for line in open(thisfilename+'intermediate.csv'):
 if "spend" in line:
   print line
   print line.split(":")[-1]
```

That worked the trick for me.